# Global variable in Struct using mutating function/map doesn't changing value when updating

Tags: ios, swift, struct, rx-swift

In View Controller

```
viewModel.frequentDate = Date() // This changes frequently
```

In ViewModel

```
struct ViewModel {
   var frequentDate = Date()
   mutating func validateSomeTime(startDatePicker: Observable<Date>) {
      self.validdate = startDatePicker.map(someValid)
   }
    
   func someValid(_ date: Date) -> String {
      if date = self.frequentDate {
         return "Done"
      }
   }
}
```

`frequentDate` doesn't change frequently it always give first initial date. When I call observable `validate` the date value is initial one not updates the latest.

this `self.frequentDate` will never change of the VC lift cycle.

*But if I changed ViewModel struct to class. It works fine*

Comment: Yes, because structs are value types. When you mutate a struct it creates a new instance and mutates that. Any other variables will still hold the original struct.

Comment: Can you also tell how you are instantiating the viewModel? Basically check the life cycle of the viewModel in your View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

@Paulw11 mentioned a good point. You should probably make your viewModel a `class` and control its lifecycle in `ViewController`. The simplest way to do it is to instantiate your `ViewModel` directly inside `ViewController`

```
class ChurchesViewController {
  let viewModel = ChurchesViewModel()
}
```

But what to do if your `ViewModel` uses some repositories, managers etc.? Well, you should inject `ViewModel` into `ViewController` somewhere else. In a simplest architecture such as MVVM-C you will probably use `Coordinator` to construct your flow:

```
class ChurchesCoordinator: Coordinator {

  init(navigationController: UINavigationController, firstManager: FirstManager, secondManager: SecondManager) { ... }

  func start() {
    let vc = ChurchesViewController() // any instantiation method
    let vm = ChurchesViewModel(firstManager: self.firstManager, secondManager: self.secondManager)
    vc.viewModel = vm
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

This is a simple example, but I personally use a library for DI called Dip or Swinject, it simplifies things a lot. If you to choose other architectures, probably you will have another modules to make a DI.